# Converting http_params to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can obtain an array from the string

```
http_params="created_end_date=2013-02-28&created_start_date=2013-01-01&page_size=50&offset=0&order_id=0D1108211501118%0D%0A0D11108211501118%0D%0Ac%0D%0AD%0D%0ADK212071409743%0D%0AKK30109110100%0D%0AKK30111140300%0D%0AKK30111140400%0D%0AKK30115120100%0D%0AKK30115150100&page_number=1"
```

So I did `myarray=http_params.split("&")`:

```
myarray=["created_end_date=2013-02-28", "created_start_date=2013-01-01", "page_size=50", "offset=0", "order_id=0D1108211501118%0D%0A0D11108211501118%0D%0Ac%0D%0AD%0D%0ADK212071409743%0D%0AKK30109110100%0D%0AKK30111140300%0D%0AKK30111140400%0D%0AKK30115120100%0D%0AKK30115150100", "page_number=1"]
```

I need to convert this to a hash myhash, so that I can make a Rest Client post call for myhash.to_json. Basically it should be key,value pairs like:

```
{:created_end_date=>"2013-02-28",:created_start_date=>"2013-01-01"....}
```

I know that the inverse operation can be done like this:

```
http_params = myhash.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')
```

but I am unable to come up with neat code for this.

What's the best way I should go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'cgi'
hash = CGI::parse http_params
```

Or you can use:

```
hash = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query http_params
```

Which does not return the values as arrays.

Comment: The keys are strings, but for some reason the values become single element arrays: `{"created_end_date"=>["2013-02-28"], "created_start_date"=>["2013-01-01"], ...}`. I wonder why.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing....When I do hash.to_json I get {\"created_end_date\":[\"2013-02-28\"]...}

Comment: I edited the answer. You should go with `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` if you don't want the values to be arrays.

Answer (score 2):

With pure Ruby methods, you can convert your string into a Hash as follows:

```
"a=1&b=2".split('&').map { |h| Hash[*h.split("=")] }
=> [{"a"=>"1"}, {"b"=>"2"}]
```

A blog post how to operate on Ruby collections is here: http://thinkingonthinking.com/map-reduce-in-ruby/

To get symbols as keys, a small additional step is necessary:

```
"a=1&b=2".split('&').map { |h| hs = h.split("="); Hash[hs[0].to_sym, hs[1]] }
=> [{:a=>"1"}, {:b=>"2"}]
```

As last step, a merge of the inner Hash elements has to be done. This can be done like:

```
"a=1&b=2".split('&').map { |h| hs = h.split("="); Hash[hs[0].to_sym, hs[1]] }.inject({}) { |s, h| s.merge(h) }
=> {:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the desired output though.

Comment: I added an example that should show how to use to_sym to get a symbol key

Comment: I wasn't talking about symbols vs strings. This returns an array with lots of hashes in it. He seems to want a single hash with lots of elements. E.g. `{ :a => '1', :b => '2' }`

Comment: What happens if you have array fields? This happens a lot when you use checkboxes...

Comment: Ok, I agree, a Ruby version for doing this process is not working very well for the checkbox case.

Comment: hmm.. I think this is the part in Rack that filters the checkboxes out: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L104